# Aging Report Query Error

Tags: php

I use this MySQL query for getting 120 days old data from current date but it can't work.

```
SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE (DateDiff("d", Date(), voucher.vou_date) > 120);
```

Please point out my error with easy solution.

Comment: "but it can't work" - Do you get any error messages? I so, please provide them.

Comment: @AlexThomas Showing Error: 1064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateDiff(Date(), voucher.vou_date) > 120
```

Comment: Yes, `date()` is only date part not time and `now()` have both